# "Лиха беда начало" как понять? Этимология выражения не совсем ясна

Tags: пунктуация, этимология, фразеология, грамматика

Во-первых, где склонение или пунктуация? Во-вторых, где хоть какой-то смысл?

Если отбросить "лиха", то получается "беда - начало", начало-беда. По смыслу это подходит под то, что мы привыкли понимать, произнося эту поговорку. Самое трудное - начать.

Пускай тире упустили и забыли, что оно должно быть. Но основной вопрос -  что такое "лиха беда"? "Лиха" это сокращение от "лихая". *Лихой* имеет несколько значений: удалой, злой, преступный. Ничего из этого не подходит к слову беда.

Comment: Было: *произнося эту проверку*. Я верно поняла Вашу описку, заменив на *произнося эту поговорку*?

Comment: А ведь если поменять последнюю букву – "о" на "а" – иными словами, поменять именительный падеж на родительный, то всё будет предельно логично: "лиха беда начала", то бишь у всякого начала есть своя беда (свои проблемы, связанные с начинанием какого-либо дела или преприятия) и она весьма лиха (то есть проблемы те поначалу непредсказуемы, их природа ещё не изучена, ещё нету никаких навыков в том, как с ними справляться и т.д.)

Answer (score 7):

Ничего, если я немного погуглила?..

> **Лиха бѣда начало!** (иноск.) всякое начало трудно; стоитъ только начать, а тамъ пойдетъ.
>
> *Хоть для пробы маленькое дѣльце завели бы... Лиха бѣда начать, а тамъ все какъ по маслу пойдетъ (Мельниковъ. Въ лѣсахъ).*
>
> ---

[**Что означает слово «лиха»?**](http://1-kak.ru/255-liha-beda-nachalo-znachenie.html#p5)

> В данном случае «лиха» – сокращение от прилагательного «лихая». Причем
>   в словаре В. И. Даля толкования этому прилагательному даны довольно
>   различные – от «молодой» до «лукавый». Здесь же мы можем четко
>   проследить взаимосвязь со словом «залихватский», то есть задорный.
>   Такое довольно легкомысленное отношение к проблеме – типичная черта
>   русского национального характера.
>
> Также можно вспомнить мифологического персонажа – лихо,
>   символизирующее несчастья и несправедливую судьбу (вспомним «не буди
>   лихо, пока оно тихо»).  Это слово встречается и в других выражениях,
>   например, «лиха беда хлеб нажить, а с хлебом можно паном жить». Тут мы
>   прослеживаем довольно пренебрежительное отношение к проблеме (как в
>   случае с «залихватским»).

[**Откуда взялось это выражение?**](http://1-kak.ru/255-liha-beda-nachalo-znachenie.html#p5)

> ...Некоторые приписывают первое упоминание этой фразы Петру Великому,
>   который произнес ее, сделав смысловое ударение на слове «беда», имея в
>   виду важность планирования перед каким-либо делом, иначе неприятностей
>   не избежать. Однако со временем значение поменялось.
>
> Даже если сравнить это выражение с похожими в других языках (особенно
>   в латинском и славянских), то будет ясно, что фраза приобрела новую
>   эмоциональную окраску, а именно: самое главное в любом деле – начать
>   его и не бояться последствий (то есть это как раз то значение, которое
>   мы используем сейчас).
>
> ---

[**Вопрос № 248688**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=248688)

> "Лиха беда начало". Требуется ли тире?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка:**
>
> Ставить тире нет необходимости.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Значение**

**ЛИХОЙ,** 2. **Полный тягот, бед; тяжёлый**, трудный (о времени). Лихая им досталась доля . Лиха беда начало (начать).

**БЕДА,**  Очень большая неприятность; несчастье, горе. Беда приключилась. Навлечь, отвести беду. Попасть в беду.

Но слово "беда" может иметь и **различные переносные значения:** Грибников в лесу ― просто беда! Беда мне с ним!  Беда, кто в свет рождён с чувствительной душой! (Пушкин). Я вас разбудил? ― Не велика беда!

Также **бедой можно назвать затруднение, испытание**, учитывая, что начальное значение слова ― притеснение, гонение, принуждение (от нем. beiten ― принуждать). Из этого следует, что в современном понимании "лиха беда" - **это трудное (тяжелое) испытание, принуждение.**

**2. Пунктуация**

Лиха беда начало. Тире не ставится, так как здесь **инверсия** подлежащего и сказуемого (начало ― это лиха беда (сложное дело)). Сравнить: Славное место эта долина!

Answer (score 2):

> Пускай тире упустили и забыли, что оно должно быть.

Нет, не забыли. Не будь выражение устоявшимся, вопрос о тире был бы правомерен. Но в подобном законченном и самодостаточном сочетании оно излишне.

> Но основной вопрос - что такое "лиха беда"?

"Лихой" здесь "тяжелый", "трудный", в сочетании с бедой годится "большой", "сильный". Все эти значения есть в более подробных словарях.

Да собственно, обычный толковый словарь даёт достаточно оснований для такого понимания.

> 1. ЛИХОЙ, -ая, -ое; лих, -а, -о, лихи и лихи. 1. Нар.-разг. и нар.-поэт. Могущий причинить вред, зло; злой. Л. враг. Л. муж. Л.
>      человек; л-ие люди (устар.; о разбойниках). // Свойственный злому
>      человеку, выражающий недоброжелательность, злобу. Л-ое слово. Л. глаз.
>      Л. поступок. 2. Полный тягот, бед; тяжёлый, трудный (о времени). Л-ая
>      пора. Л-ая година. Л. час. / Суровый, драматический (о жизни, судьбе и
>      т.п. кого-л.). Л-ая судьба. Л-ая жизнь. * Лихая им досталась доля
>      (Лермонтов). ◊ Лиха беда начало (начать). Трудно только начать. <Лихо
>      (см. 2. Л.).

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x

Ну а значение всего выражения уже объяснили.

---

> Лихой имеет несколько значений: удалой, злой, преступный. Ничего из
>   этого не подходит к слову беда.

Я, собственно, уже ответил на это, значения шире, но переспрошу. А чем вам "злая беда" не подходит-то?

Answer (score 1):

Как только не искажают отвечающие это выражение синтаксически! А меж тем Sharon всё основное сказала. Подытожу коротко.

**Лихой** — полный тягот, тяжёлый.
**Беда** — большая неприятность.

Теперь смысл: ***начало — это лихая беда.*** Подставляем определения и получаем: ***начало — это тяжёлая неприятность*** или (если перефразировать) **полное тягот время.**

"Лиха" — краткое прилагательное, свойственное более старому языку, то же, что "лихая".
Как отметила Sharon, здесь использована ***инверсия:*** подлежащее "начало" стоит в конце выражения и сказуемое "лиха беда" — в начале.

Answer (score 0):

В слове "лихо" есть еще одно значение, здесь не рассмотренное. Хотя оно вторичное, производное, но в старину часто употреблявшееся. Значение: лишнее, неуместное.
Так от "лихо" образуется сложное слово "лихоимсто", - один из грехов, в которых следует каяться. "Лихоимство" означает стяжательство сверх меры, приобретение лишнего, без чего можно было бы обойтись. Лишнее отягчает душу, а в узкие врата Царствия Небесного с лишним не протиснуться.
"Лиха беда начало" говорит о непредвиденных трудностях, возникающих в начале дела, как правильно все здесь замечают. Но эта беда, эти трудности к самому делу не относятся, оно в них не нуждается, они лишние.

Comment: (не получается исправить одну букву, пропустили в первом слове "лихоимсто"). Согласен с тем, что лихо - это лишнее. Есть ещё одно слово "лиходей" - совершает непонятные дела. Лиха беда - стало быть лишённая беды... начало не беда.

Comment: Очень сомнительное толкование. Неплохо бы подкрепить его ссылкой на толковый словарь. Пока что это больше смахивает на полёт фантазии.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда воспринимал пословицу как "лиха беда началА". Беда чего? Беда начала. Начинать трудно, это беда. Но эта беда быстро проходит, потому что она лиха/лихая/быстрая/скоротечная.

Comment: Несмотря на минуса, хочу отметить, что Михаил не одинок в подобном понимании. Гуглокниги находят "лиха беда началА" в больших количествах, в том числе в солидных изданиях. Но ясно, что версия ошибочна, поскольку выражение "лиха беда" распространено само по себе, а также встречается в других поговорках и пословицах. Ещё можно вспомнить "лиха беда начать" и "лиха беда почин", которые не вписываются в предложенное Михаилом объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Может надо понимать, что любая беда страшнее всего вначале, а дальше проще. И поэтому произносить фразу нужно: "Лиха беда началом". Лично по своему опыту могу сказать, что это так.

Comment: Личный опыт — не то, что убеждает. Нужны знания и их источник.

Answer (score -1):

Лихо — большое испытание, трудное дело.
Для того, чтобы решиться пройти лихо, то есть взяться и выполнить трудное дело, требуется получить некий пинок. В качестве такого пинка в данном контексте подразумевается беда, некая неприятность. Можно сказать так:
"Начало (чего?) лиха — беда". Тот же смысл подразумевается при перестановке порядка слов, то есть при инверсии: "лиха беда начало". А в этой формулировке паузы (соответственно, и тире, обозначающего эту паузу) перед словом "начало" не требуется.

Comment: Не находите «взаимосвязь со словом «залихватский», то есть задорный»? Не согласны с Далем? Кстати, порядка слов он менять не мыслил.